# Check if internet connection is available (https)

Tags: java, android

I would like to check if the android app has an internet connection available.
I tried this could, which is not working due to the Googles requirement of https.

```
private static boolean netIsAvailable() {
    try {
        final URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        final URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        conn.getInputStream().close();
        return true;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        return false;
    }
```

I am getting the error: `java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to www.google.com not permitted`

Which other ways there are?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect whether there is an Internet connection available on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android)

Comment: @Jason Please don't copy paste code from that link as all top answers contain code that's deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager is an option:

Something like:

```
 NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities = mConnectivityService.getNetworkCapabilities(mConnectivityService.getActiveNetwork());
                if (networkCapabilities != null) {
                    if (networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)) {

                        // do something with internet
                    } else {
                        // no internet
                    }
                } else {
                    // no internet
                }
```

Although, is there a reason why you cannot just use `https` in your URL?

Comment: just use https will lead to `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: what ist `mConnectivityService` ?

Comment: That is because you're trying to do the request on main thread, do it as an `AsyncTask` or similar

Comment: `mConnectivityService` is `ConnectivityManager`; `mConnectivityService = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);`

Comment: This seems to be working: private boolean netIsAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

Comment: Similar to what I've used in the past!